# Check if variable is different from several values

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

If I want to take an action if php if a variable isn't 0,1, or 2, how would I do that? my if statement isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Next time you should attempt to summarize the question in the title; "easy php question" gives no more information than the tags.

Comment: This is just a case of too many `if`'s in the question. Maybe you should go with a `switch`! ;)

Comment: `switch ($x) { case 0: case 1: case 2: break; default: /* take action */ }`?  Eeewwwwww.  :)

Answer (score 7):

```
if (($var != 0) && ($var != 1) && ($var != 2)) {
    //...
}
```

or...

```
if (!in_array($var, array(0, 1, 2))) { /* ... */ }
```

See [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: @Leticia: You should also post your code next time so we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: @Let I'd advise to read a bit more about PHP before starting to write scripts. You can start here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward way:

```
if ($x != 0 && $x != 1 && $x != 2)
{
    // take action!
}
```

If you know your variable is an int, then you could also do like:

```
if ($x < 0 || $x > 2)
{
    // take action!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `&&` operator to chain tests, and test non-equality with `!==` which checks type *and* value:

```
if( $n !== 0 && $n !== 1 && $n !== 2 ) {
     // it's not any of those values.
}
```

The `==` operator will coerce values, so all the following are true:

- 0 == 'foo'
- 99 == '99balloons'
- true == 1
- false == ''

And so on. See [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more information about `==` vs. `===`. Also check the table "Comparison with Various Types" to better understand how types are coerced if you are comparing non-numbers. Only you can determine if `if( $n < 0 || $n > 2 )` will meet your needs. (Well, we can help, but we need more details.)

See [logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for more on `&&` and `||`.

Comment: `if ($n < 0 && $n > 2)` will never meet the right needs.  It can never be true.  :)